# Specify paths for Icons

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, cocoa

**OK, so here's my situation :**

- My app graphics are not copied into the Bundle's resources folder, but into a subfolder (e.g. `Resources/Graphics`)
- I need to properly set the icons - either for the app icon, or the document types associated with the app - in the **info.plist**

**However, here's the issue :**

- If I set `CFBundleIconFile = "myicon";` and `myicon.icns` is in the *Resources* bundle folder, it works fine.
- If `myicon.icns` is in the `Graphics` subfolder, then - even if I set a path like `CFBundleIconFile = "Graphics/myicon";` or `CFBundleIconFile = "Graphics/myicon.icns";` - it doesn't seem to pick it up.

So, any ideas how this can be fixed? (obviously without telling me to copy the .icns in the *Resources* folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subfolder doesn't matter in this case, `so you dont need to set the full path, only file name, without extension`.

`CFBundleIconFile = "myicon";`

this line will be enough for the app to load the correct file from the bundle.
You aren't allowed to have several *icon* files with same name in one project/bundle.
You aren't required to copy the files into `Resources` folder, only thing is that the file must be added to the project.

Comment: Well, I've got a few issues with this answer : a) Obviously, I have tried this way (*exactly* as you say), and it's **not** working. b) Are you sure about the project bundle not being allowed to have more than 1 file with the same name? (what if they are on different subfolders (in the bundle I mean?))

Comment: You can have multiple files in different folders but i don't think that you are supposed to have multiple files. Doesn't make send to have several app different app icons and there is `Warning: Multiple build commands for output file ...` if you have duplicated files in the app. Did you try to set the icons from the project properties? Sorry if I offend you.

Comment: "offend me"? In what way? By trying to help me? Of course not, mate. :-) Now, as for the "multiple files with the same name" issue, I have quite lots of them, but they're not icon files (they're just files I'm using internally). Hmmm... as for the icons, I think the weird part comes from Xcode 4's awkward handling of project subfolders (instead of groups) - and yep, I'm using lots of folders (perhaps a bit unorthodox, but that way my huge 300-class project remains quite browseable... :-)). Greetings from your neighbours from the South! ;-)

Comment: Try to load image from group not from folder. Greetings from your neighbors from North :)

Comment: To be honest, I'm about to write some custom shell script and just copy all icon files to `Resources` root at compile time... so that every one is happy - keep the folder structure as it is and put the icons where osx wants them to be... (well, I've been patient enough with that... :p)

Comment: That seems okay, so in this way you will be able to navigate easily through the project and in the end OSX will be able to pick the right files.